# QT - QTimer with multiple QGLWidgets

Tags: qt, qglwidget, qtimer

I have an application with two QGLWidgets that are updated by the same timer, running at 60Hz. Strangely, the maximum fps I reach is exactly 30Hz. If I add a third QGLWidget (note that this third one is updated by an additional timer) I achieve 20 fps maximum on each widget. CPU load of the main thread is far from 100%. Seems to me that there is a dependency on the number of QGLWidgets and the refresh rate of my monitor as the number of used widgets multiplied by the max. fps equals the refresh rate (60Hz)...

Anyone knows what exactly is going on?

Comment: A wild guess: you have vsync on, and each widget does it separately, so they block each others while doing this.

Comment: that would absolutely make sense... I use QGL::SampleBuffers as format. Do you know whether vsync is enabled on default there? Qt homepage seems to be down...

Comment: No idea, sorry. But docs should be up by now (and then Qt SDK of course installs docs locally by default).